# Excel Lookup Not returning Proper Result

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, switch, lookup

I have a simple lookup function, which I am using in place of a Switch Case statement.

Following is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
switch(F5){
    case "apple":
        return "1";
        break;
    case "pear":
        return "2";
        break;
    case "mango":
        return "3";
        break;
    case "kiwi":
        return "4";
        break;
}
```

Below is my Excel Lookup Function:

```
=LOOKUP(F5,{"apple","pear","mango","kiwi"},{"1","2","3","4"})
```

The problem:
When F5 is equal to apple and pear I get 1, and 2 respectively and that is fine.

However, when F5 is equal to mango or kiwi I get 1, and not 3 or 4 respectively, which is what I expect.

Why is this happening? Am I using the wrong syntax?  Is the above lookup function not adequate to use in place of a switch case statement? Is there a better way of doing this?

p.s. this [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/lookup.php) talk about using the lookup function in place of a switch case statement

Comment: I don't have Excel in front of me, but I'm guessing it has to do with alphabetical order of your lookup values. Try sorting and see if it fixes your issue. I also think there's a switch in the lookup function for exact value that may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOOKUP function requires the lookup range (your fruits) to be in ascending order

Try changing the order like this

`=LOOKUP(F5,{"apple","kiwi","mango","pear"},{"1","4","3","2"})`

....although if F5 is **lemon** that will give you 4 rather than #N/A so for exact match only you could use `HLOOKUP` like this [doesn't require sorting]

`=HLOOKUP(F5,{"apple","pear","mango","kiwi";"1","2","3","4"},2,0)`

Comment: Awesome! I'm using HLOOKUP now!